# How to insert original line number in g/pattern/move

Tags: vim

vim: insert original line number in `g/pattern/move $`

I'm debugging some event order in a log and like to check two set of events sequence by the line number of the showing log. Usually, I used g/pattern/move $ for some interesting info. But I cannot find a way to insert the original line number of them. Please help.

I tried :
`g/pattern/move $; printf("%d",line("."))`
but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't help thinking of something very straightforward, for example:

```
g/pattern/call append(line('$'), line('.') . ' ' . getline('.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different way but I have following mapping in my `_vimrc`

```
nnoremap <F3> :redir! @f<cr>:silent g//<cr>:redir! END<cr>:enew!<cr>:put! f<cr>:let @f=@/<cr>:g/^$/d<cr>:let @/=@f<cr>gg
```

It opens a new buffer with all your search matches, including the linenumbers where the match occured.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to insert at first the line number on the lines that have the pattern and after that moving the same lines to the end of the file:

```
:%s,\v^\ze.*pattern,\=line('.') . ' ' ,g | g/pattern/m$
```

We have two commands:

```
:%s,\v^\ze.*pattern,\=line('.') . ' ' ,g

, ....................... we are using comma as delimiter
\v ...................... very magic substitution
^ ....................... Regular expression for beginning of line
\ze ..................... indicates that all after it will not be substituted
\=line('.') ............. gets the line number
. ' '  .................. concatenates one space after the number
```

The second command is separated with `|`

```
g/pattern/m$

m$ ....................... moves the pattern to the end of file
```